# ActionLink not producing the correct link

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, actionlink

I am using MVC 2, and having a slight issue with the ActionLink not going to the correct controller

The following line of code, which displays a logoff link

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account", new { @class = "loginStatus" })%>
```

It does not appear to be going to the Account controller

The link it is make is:

```
http://localhost:63262/Centre/Schedule/LogOff?Length=7
```

it should be

```
http://localhost:63262/Authentication/Account/LogOff?Length=7
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Paste routing initializing from global.asax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following link which answers my question, it's more to do with Areas and Routes:

http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/10/13/asp-net-mvc2-preview-2-areas-and-routes.aspx

Here is the solution to my issue

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account", new { area="" }, null)%>
```

Answer (score 2):

Be mindful of the ActionLink() overload you're calling.  You think you're calling the overload http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx, but you're really calling the overload http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124.aspx.  Add a *null* to the end of your parameter list.